# laravel display image from database with blade

Tags: laravel, image, laravel-blade

i just stored the path of a image that i uploaded into the database, however in the edit section of the form i want to show it and dont seem to find how is the right way to display it i have been trying with:

{{ HTML::image('imgs/picture.jpg') }} -> this one shows the path correctly BUT
using -> {!! Html::image('product_image') !!} doesnt display the path correctly if i use the chrome developer tools inspector i get this:

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/product_image">
```

what am i doing wrong? what i want is to display the info (the path of the image) that is stored on the database.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use `Storage::url()` ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-urls

```php
{{ HTML::image(Storage::url('imgs/picture.jpg')) }}
//or
{{ HTML::image(Storage::url($product_image)) }} // here $product_image database path stored by Storage::put() function
```

it will generate url for laravel storage path like

`<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/imgs/picture.jpg">`  it is correct path

Comment: if i put it like you suggested it displays:
<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/product_image">
what i need is to show the information that comes from the database

Comment: `Storage::url()` inside `url(databasePath)` u need to use like this is the way official doc say to use filesystem

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: @SolarConfinement i added you can check